# Running the program with Python as hidden

Tags: python, windows, hidden

I want to run .exe files hidden in Windows using Python.
I used the following commands,but the hidden program does not run.

```
from subprocess_maximize import Popen

Popen(r"C:\Apps\test.exe",show='hidden', priority=1)
```

Comment: Hidden console or hidden window?

Comment: hidden window...

Answer (score 2):

if you want python hide cmd console Use :

```
import win32gui, win32con

hide = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hide , win32con.SW_HIDE)
```

or if you want to hide cmd from python use :

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow( ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 6 )
```

Else Save the program with a `.pyw` extension and now it will open with `pythonw.exe` No shell or cmd window

Comment: Thanks...
But I want, for example, if the psiphon program runs, its window will be hidden